# ISEXP : warning : -6245: One or more of the project's components contain .NET properties that require the .NET Framework

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, installshield

I am getting a "Warning -6245" when I try to build a Windows application by using InstallShield LE for VS 2013. How can I find out which file in the installation package (consisting of many executables, DLLs, OCXs etc.) requires .NET framework and which version of .NET framework is required? This warning does not give me any hint on either the file(s) requiring .NET or the needed version of the .NET.  I can add a .NET version to be installed to fulfill this requirement but don't I need to know the version of the required .NET? Would the latest .NET version be compatible for the requiring program in the package?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely add the version of .NET framework that projects are based on. Go to Project Properties and find out.

Comment: I had added version 4.6 and the warning is gone. But, I still would like to  know which  program component in the package needs which version of .NET.  Since InstallShield warns the user it must know. Where is this reported?

Comment: I guess it does not identify the component dependency itself. Rather it relies on the configuration of the project. If the project has a dependency on a particular version, InstallShield would detect and infer that the project would require that particular version for working properly.

Answer (score 0):

The warning error -6245 is gone when I added the .NET version 4.6 into the project. This is the latest version InstallShield LE provides. But it would be nice to know .NET requirements of individual components of the installation package. Maybe full version of IS reports this.